# Running convert command of image magic using Java gives unable to load module error

Tags: java, imagemagick

I have written a class that execute convert command of imagemagic.

```
public class ImageMagicDemo {

public static void main(String[] argp){


    ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("G:\\project\\installation\\imagemagic\\convert","G:\\demo\\image\\frame.jpg", "-resize", "20x20",
            "G:\\demo\\image\\resizeImage\\frame1.jpg");
    pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process p2;
    try {
        p2 = pb2.start();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("2"+p2.waitFor());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

But I am getting the following response

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `G:\demo\image\frame.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2692.
convert.exe: unable to load module `G:\project\installation\imagemagic\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': The specified module could not be found.
@ error/module.c/OpenModule/1282.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: no images defined `G:\demo\image\resizeImage\frame1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
```

Same problem is with .png file.I have installed ImageMagick-6.9.1-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe on Window8.
However if I run the following command on command prompt

```
convert -resize 1024x768 G:\\demo\\image\\frame.jpg G:\\demo\\image\\resizeImage\\frame1.jpg
```

It successfully execute and copy the resized image in destination folder.If anyone knows please reply.

Thanks

Comment: You can also change the the working directory the command is executed in, but your parameters for ProcessBuilder don't match the command line parameters...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, there was a spelling mistake in file name and -resize parameter have no effect as they are defining dimensions only. But this does not work when the command is run from java program. I have tried this by installing the imagemagic in "Program File" directory also. But no luck in that case also.

Comment: Are you using a 64 or 32 bit version of  ImageMagic? What about Java, 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: I can get it to work, only when I use `ProcessBuilder#directory(File)` and pass it the location of the `convert.exe`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, after using ProcessBuilder#directory(File), problem get solved. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get it to work, only if I change the working directory from which the executed is to be run, using `ProcessBuilder#directory(File)`

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\\convert.exe",
                "C:\\Path\to\Large.png",
                "-resize", "1027x768",
                "C:\\Path\to\small.png");

try {
    pb.inheritIO();
    pb.redirectErrorStream();
    pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    try (InputStream is = p.getInputStream()) {
        int in = -1;
        while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)in);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Exited with " + p.waitFor());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it allready helped to install the *static* Version of ImageMagick instead off the *dynamic/dll*. Give it a try. Btw. call-funktionality should be same with x86 or x64.